# how to Auto-adjusting height of react-native-swiper component

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I'm using `react-native-swiper`, but when I implement it, it's set to default height full screen.
Is there a way to have the swiper height automatically adjust to the slide content (height)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this work using `height="100%"` for the Swiper

```
<Swiper
      loop
      autoplay
      autoplayTimeout={5}
      height='100%'
>
</Swiper>
```